# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException Decryption error when trying to use HttpURLConnection on https URL

Tags: java, encryption, httpurlconnection, badpaddingexception

I'm trying to use webservice from java application. The webservice site is served through https.

I write this code, but javax.crypto.BadPaddingException Decryption error is appearing.

```
try{
     URL url = new URL("https://www.google.ne.jp");
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); <= error
```

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: Can't reproduce, neither with JDK 1.7.0_45, nor with java 1.8.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

My JDK is 1.7.0.76.
I tried to change JDK 1.7.0.45 and java 1.8.
but, it's reproduced...

Anything else? 
What is required settings?

Comment: My guess is that you're behind some kind of nasty proxy that mess things up.

Comment: I check proxy settings, but not set. so, I set up another eclipse environment that import same code. It worked fine... I don't know what is the cause... but, it worked fine. it's ok. thanks.